# How to specify args to python thread, and pass nothing?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Notice this happens in python 2.7, and probably doesn't in python 3

How can I specify the args keyword when passing arguments to a thread, but pass zero arguments?

```
mythread = threading.Thread(name='the_name', target=self._handle,
                                            args=[])

def _handle(self):
    pass
```

gives the error:

> _handle() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I want to

1. Not omit the `args=` keyword
2. Have no args passed

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

`[]` is not nothing, it is an empty array. Try:

```
mythread = threading.Thread(name='the_name', target=self._handle,
                                        args=())
```

And the class definition:

```
def _handle(self, *args):
    pass
```

Full reproductible code on my side:

```
import threading


class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _handle(self, *args):
        pass

    def cthread(self):
        mythread = threading.Thread(name='the_name', target=self._handle,
                                        args=())
        mythread.start()
        return mythread
b = a()
b.cthread()
```

Comment: Indeed, you need to pass an empty list of arguments, I have updated the code and checked it.

Comment: In my example, _handle doesn't declare `*args`. is it mandatory? in the case that I am passing empty arguments to it

Comment: `*args` is a placeholder for any non keyword argument. I think it is needed here since you want to define `args` so something will be passed, even `None` or anything else.

Comment: I don't get it. When I do `def _handle(self, *args):`, or `def _handle(self):` I get `_handle_receiver_thread() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` when specifying `args=()`. Why would it expect 2 arguments?

Comment: When `_handle` is a `@staticmethod` and i pass `self` as `args=[self]` it seems to work fine. I think some lambda or binding magic happens there and I'm not aware of

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Thanks for trying! Python 2.7, if I pass self as an argument to target=ClassName._handle, it doesnt have problems. If i pass no args (just not specifying them, or passing None or ()), it wants a different number of arguments. For now i just pass it as args=[self]. Would love to know why it behaves this way

Comment: First, I use only Python3 and it was I used to test my example. Indeed the behaviour is odd with Python2; and I would like to know what change in class design caused that.